# Is there a reason why something like `list[]` raises `SyntaxError` in Python?

Tags: python, list, syntax

Let's say that I want to implement my custom `list` class, and I want to override `__getitem__` so that the `item` parameter can be initialized with a default `None`, and behave accordingly:

```
class CustomList(list):
    def __init__(self, iterable, default_index):
        self.default_index = default_index
        super().__init__(iterable)

    def __getitem__(self, item=None):
        if item is None:
            item = self._default_index
        return super().__getitem__(item)

iterable = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
my_list = CustomList(iterable, 2)
```

This allows for `my_list[None]`, but it would be awesome to have something like `my_list[]` inherently use the default argument.

Unfortunately that raises `SyntaxError`, so I'm assuming that the statement is illegal at the grammar level...my question is: **why**? Would it conflict with some other statements?

I'm very curious about this, so thanks a bunch to anyone willing to explain!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its not syntactically useful. There isn't a useful way to programatically use `my_list[]` without literally hard-coding it as such. A single piece of code can't sometimes have a variable in the list reference and other times not. In that case, why not just have a different property that gets the default?

```
@property
def default(self):
    return super().__getitem__(self.default)
@property.setter
def default(self, val):
    super().__setitem__(self.default, val)
```

`object.__getitem__(self, val)` is defined to have a required positional argument. Python is dynamic and so you can get away with changing that call signature, but that doesn't change how all the other code uses it.

All python operators have a magic method behind them and its always the case that the magic method could expose more features than the operator. Why not let `+` have a default? So, `a = b +`  would be legal. Once again, that would not be syntactically useful - you could just expose a function if you want to do that.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation; it makes sense that they wouldn't implement it without a tangible benefit. Also, I found the addition of a dedicated property a good solution, so thanks for adding that too!

Answer (score -1):

`__getitem__` always takes exactly one argument. You can kindof pass multiple arguments, but this actually just converts it into a tuple:

```py
>>> a = []
>>> a[1, 2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Note the "not tuple" in the error message.

Comment: This has nothing to do with why specifying _no_ index is a syntax error

Comment: "always takes exactly one argument", i.e. no argument is not allowed. How does that not answer the question?

Comment: @Possseidon actually I wasn't trying to mess with `__getitem__` signature, but just to set a default value and use an 'empty' indexing notation, in a similar fashion as when you call a function with empty parentheses.

Comment: I meant `__getitem__` as synonymous with indexing itself. Sorry if that wasn't clear. Indexing itself is what always takes exactly one parameter, which I tried to illustrate with the example.